# Using Oracle's regexp_like I need an exclusive or match

Tags: regex, oracle

I need an expression that will provide an exclusive match on the first match it gets and I don't know if this can be done with Oracle's regexp_like or not:

Suppose I have a string " some stuff Ichabod somestuff  Crane somestuff ", I want it to match on Ichabod but not Crane but then I want an expression that will match "Crane" but not Ichabod. At the same time if I have "Ichabod" that needs to match for the Ichabod search pattern and "Crane" has to match for the "Crane" pattern. Effectively I'm trying to categorize a bunch of strings and "Ichabod Crane" belongs in the Ichabod category and "Crane Ichabod" belongs in the Crane category.

By the way I've tried something like (?Ichabod) which seems to work but (?!Ichabod) or (?!anypattern) never matches anything; seems to be a limitation of Oracle's regexp_like.

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Why is "Ichabod Crane" in Ichabod and "Crane Ichabod" in Crane? Is it based on the first occurrence of the keyword?

Comment: Yes, first occurrence of the keyword. The answer from Kevin Kirkpatrick should work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't squeeze that kind IF-THEN-ELSE logic into a single REGEXP function.  Instead, I'd use distinct REGEXP_INSTR for each pattern, then use CASE logic to return the REGEXP_SUBSTR of whichever pattern had the lowest non-zero REGEXP_INSTR index:

```
select  str, 
        case 
          when regexp_instr(str,'b') = 0
            then regexp_substr(str,'f')
          when regexp_instr(str,'f') = 0
            then regexp_substr(str,'b')
          when regexp_instr(str,'b') = least(regexp_instr(str,'b'),regexp_instr(str,'f'))
            then regexp_substr(str,'b')
          else regexp_substr(str,'f')
          end matched_substr
from (select 'abcdefg'  str from dual union all
      select 'afcdebg'  str from dual union all
      select 'abcdeg'   str from dual union all
      select 'acdefg'   str from dual union all
      select 'acdeg'    str from dual);

╔═════════╦════════════════╗
║   STR   ║ MATCHED_SUBSTR ║
╠═════════╬════════════════╣
║ abcdefg ║ b              ║
║ afcdebg ║ f              ║
║ abcdeg  ║ b              ║
║ acdefg  ║ f              ║
║ acdeg   ║                ║
╚═════════╩════════════════╝
```

Of course, if you were only looking to use REGEXP to implement the "get whichever comes first", and your actual pattern matching is simple string matching, you'll want to replace REGEXP_INSTR and REGEXP_SUBSTR with simple INSTR and SUBSTR.